# Retrieve data from Properties file in Java

Tags: java

I have a static array list in my code. Now I want that should be moved to the properties file so that if there is any change or modification in future I have simply change the values in properties file and it will be reflected everywhere where it is used.

As of now static code is like this:

```
ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();
dataList.add("A");
dataList.add("B");
dataList.add("E");
dataList.add("G");
dataList.add("H");
dataList.add("P");
dataList.add("W");



ArrayList TypeList = new ArrayList();
TypeList.add(new Brand("A", "Test1"));
TypeList.add(new Brand("B", "Test2"));
TypeList.add(new Brand("E", "Test3"));
TypeList.add(new Brand("G", "Test4"));
```

I have tried this but this is not working:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("/displayCategerization.properties"));
```

I want both of them to be dynamic and the values should be picked from properties file. How can I do this?

Comment: What is not working? Explain the problem. Is there any exception? post the stack trace.

Comment: this contains answer for you http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: no i am not able to create to understand how i will the key and value in the file should i use xml for that and how  i can access that

Comment: Provide the structure of your application (directories, packages, files, ...) and tell us where does your **displayCategerization.properties** reside?

Comment: in the resources folder  i have the displayCategerization.properties

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
private static Properties props = null;

public static void load(String configFilePath) {
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(configFilePath);
props = new Properties();
props.load(is);
is.close();
}

public static String getValueByKey(String key) {
        String propertyValue=null;
        if(props.containsKey(key)) {
            propertyValue = props.getProperty(key);
        }
        return propertyValue;
    }
```

Call this function during start of your program. You need to restart your program in case of properties file update

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way :-

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("Test.properties"));
    String name = prop.getProperty("name");
    String city = prop.getProperty("city");
```

Test.properties

name=xyz

city=AAA